# Error in React Native using axios - Error: Network Error

Tags: react-native, azure, ssl, axios, web-application-firewall

I'm using axios on my React Native APP and i'm getting this error on my post request -> [Error: Network Error]

A few informations that are relevants:

- This error not happen on IOS (same project)
- API is hosted on Azure.
- This error starts to happen after turn on WAF on API.

When I make the same call on postman, I receive the follow message: Unable to verify the first certificate (but the request works because SSL certificate verification is disabled.

"react-native": "^0.67.5",
"axios": "^0.26.1",
node: 14.7.0

I tried to disabled SSL Verification on Android, but I don't wanna follow this approach, because it's a security config.